# How to use dxTreeView with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, devextreme

Helloo, how i can use dx-tree-view, i wrote in my *Home.html* page the next html code:

```
<div dx-tree-view="treeViewOptions"></div>
```

and in my *HomeController.js*:

```
 $scope.treeViewOptions = {
        bindingOptions: {
            dataSource: 'myPhoneItems'
        },
        keyExpr: 'id',
        displayExpr: 'caption',
        parentIdExpr: 'parentId',
        virtualModeEnabled: true
    }
```

My apllication have *Create New Category* and  *Create New Phone* buttons,
while creating a New Phone, *Create new phone -form* have select box with *categories*, i saved data into *array of objects* and it's look liks this:
[image]

When i add some phones in my page:
[image]
when i add  th *dataStructure: "plain"* line to  *$scope.treeViewOptions = {...}* - displays nothing.
May be somebody knows how to make it correcly ? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you did not specify the root item:

> If the dataStructure option is set to 'plain', the widget requires you to specify at least one root item. An item is used as a root item if its parentId field holds 0 or null.

See this [article](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTreeView/Configuration/?version=15_2#dataStructure) as well.

But in your sample I can't see any item with parentId = 0 or `null`. Anyway, you can use any parentId to specify the root level. Just use the [rootValue](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTreeView/Configuration/?version=15_2#rootValue) option:

```
$scope.treeViewOptions = {
    //...
    rootValue: 1
};
```

I've created [the small sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/ijXYOHXqnhbtltCreFKs?p=preview) that shows it in action.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, but, i have trouble with it, i made like you,and i have the next error: "Maximum call stack size exceeded" and my tree-view  hangs and don't display all elements( Please, if you have some free-time, look my code http://pastebin.com/7EgUPG1P. Thank you. Here, screenshot with my array: http://prntscr.com/ahxr76  and here with my tree-view http://prntscr.com/ahxrci.

Comment: There are some items with the same `id` field in your code. `{caption: 'Apple', id: 1}` and `{caption: 'One', id: 1}`, for instance. But the `id` field should be unique for the each item. It may cause the issue you described.

Comment: And one more point - I've used the DevExtreme v.15.2.7 in my sample. Check if your version is the same.